# WampServer - Windows 7: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: sockets, wampserver, mysql

I am using Dreamweaver CS6. I have uploaded my website to the remote server successfully.

When I visit the website online (www.spiritual-calling.com) I get the following error message:

> "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

I've been reading a few articles like: http://nikinuryadin.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-varrunmysqldmysqld-sock-2/

but I am a newbie and don't know what the world they are talking about when they say,

> "Create the directory (if it doesn’t already exist).  #sudo mkdir
>   /var/run/mysqld/"

Could someone please explain in detail...?

I have WampServer installed on Windows 7.

I'm sorry, I don't know much about Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: So is this windows (per your tag) or linux?

Comment: I have WampServer installed on Windows 7. I'm sorry, I don't know much about Linux.

Comment: Those paths, errors and commands are all linux. Something is amiss.

Comment: how can you solve this problem? I also have met this problem,too